# i need to redirect multiple domains to the same static web URL in azure in case of a full site down....can anyone advise

Tags: azure, azure-static-website-hosting

first off i want to thank you all for the amazing information on here, i have learnt so much!

so the issue i have is i need to create a static web page for when we have a whole site down, as we host general maintenance pages on word press.i need to have multiple domains redirected to this web site when this issue occurs. the way i was thinking of doing it , is create a storage account then add to a static website to that storage container. then place the web page in a CDN adding multiple domains. then adding a cname record in DNS pointing to that endpoint? would this work?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately map multiple custom domains directly to storage accounts website is not currently supported

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/955579-enable-multiple-custom-domains-for-storage-account

You can integrate a Storage Account static website with Azure CDN and map a custom domains.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup